Maximized XTerm window: 79 lines on one system and 87 lines on another on the same 4K monitor. Why?
I have two systems, one personal and other work. Both connected to the same monitor via KVM switch.
Personal system: Fedora 39, GNome 4.
Work system: Ubuntu 22.04, XFCE
Display resolution set to 3840x2160 in both.
Maximized Xterm window size is (lines x columns)
On personal system 79x293
Work system: 87x318
.Xresource xterm*faceSize:
Personal system: 11
Work system: 15
Window scaling on both systems is 100%
Why? If anything, shouldn't I expect fewer lines on my work system (given larger faceSize?)
